# My wifi won't work, and it says Wi-fi is disabled by hardware switch

Tags: wifi-hardware-switch

I got an old computer from my grandmother, and it had Ubuntu on it. One day the wifi just switched off and said Wifi is disabled by hardware switch. How do I fix this and get the wifi back working again? Or is there a way I can just switch to Windows instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try to find physical switch that is related to wifi on/off on Your laptop.

Comment: whoops thanks. This worked. I am so stupid. 

Comment: Great, I'm glad that helped ;)

Comment: If You could accept and upvote my answer that would help me greatly, i can't type comments under original posters questions because i have insufficient rep points - that helds me off from helping people :) Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting-->Softwares and Updates--> Then click on..Additional drivers.

It will try to find drivers for Wifi.

See attached image:

[image]